# Encrypting files you create in R

Tags: r, encryption

Just want to say I am new to R. I have a file that I need to send to different clients, these clients have different passwords they use to open the file so i need to create multiple version of the file with a different password for each one. Can i create multiple files in R that are password protected? The file type is excel but it would be really handy if i can encrypt microsoft word documents as well.

Comment: There is more than one package to create Excel files in R.  What are you using.  Please show some basic code about how you created your files.

Comment: Hi, I have not written any code yet, I am having to produce the files and password them manually, I just wanted to know if it was possible to automate this in R, and what package to use?

Answer (score 3):

To create a password protected xls file in R you can use the `xlsx` package `write` function with `password` option as below:

```
write.xlsx(x, file, sheetName="Sheet2", col.names=TRUE, row.names=TRUE, append=FALSE, password=NULL)
```

For protecting and zipping any file you can use:

```
PASSWORD <- "YourPassword"

zip("C:/Users/Downloads/MyArchive.zip", 
    files="C:/Users/Downloads/example.docx", 
    flags = paste("--password", PASSWORD))
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, that's great. Is there a way to produce .docx that are password protected do you know?

Comment: You can `zip` your .docx file to password protect it. I updated the solution.

Comment: Thanks again, that is really useful. Many of our clients don't accept zip files unfortunately, so i would need to password the .docx files. I think you may be able to create codes/macros in microsoft that password protect files, so i may need to see if i can use R to create microsoft developer codes that will protect the files.

Comment: @Popesnowy Hi, we are also trying to have passwords on the .docx files we are creating using the OfficeR package. Was wondering if you managed to find a solution. Thanks.

Comment: Hi Dylan, sorry no, as far as I can see there's two options if you want to protect .docx files: (1) create a Microsoft word macro which protects files in a directory and run the macro from your r script (2) open the word file from R, and then use a KeyboardSimulator to open the appropriate toolbar/window and protect the word document like that.